# Using jQuery Highlight when a field is updated in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-highlightfade

I am working on a web application and I want to incorporate the jQuery Highlight functionality.  The way it is set up now is there is a gridview with a link button to add an entry.  When you select the link button to add an entry a form appears to fill out all of the information.  Once the information is filled out and the user selects "Insert" I would like to have the insert onClick function in the code behind somehow activate the jQuery Highlight command.  I can not seem to get this to work.  The form to insert the data is using a command field if that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clicking insert will add a row at the bottom of the table you can do the following when the dom is ready after refreshing the page;

```
$('#gridviewID tr:last td').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

Comment: I believe that this would work, however the way the site is structured is that the controls all have a masterpage they share and that masterpage will hold the jQuery code, so it does not seem to know what the gv id is on the user control..

Comment: set a specific class to the grid , cssclass='test' and find this grid like this $('table.test');

Comment: Could you specify a bit?  I am new to jQuery.  Here is what I have, the gv is in the usercontrol and has cssclass="PrettyGridView" and the jQuery is in the masterpage and says:   $('#table.PrettyGridView tr:last td').effect("highlight", {}, 3000); however I can not get it to do anything.

Comment: remove # from beginning of the table should be like this; $('table.PrettyGridView tr:last td').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);

Comment: I have done that and still nothing...code is:
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('table.PrettyGridView tr:last td').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
  });
  </script>

<asp:GridView ID="gvOptions"  CssClass="PrettyGridView" > and when I update the gv the last row is never highlighted

Comment: ok, then the version jquery you use probably doesn't support effect function. try to do this to see if that works; 

replace this;
$('table.PrettyGridView tr:last td').effect("highlight", {}, 3000); });

with this;
$('table.PrettyGridView tr:last td').css('background-color','red');

Comment: That does not work either.  I was a little off in my structure when I posted this, I realized that this is set up (by someone else not myself) as there is a masterpage, a webpage, then a user control.  I have removed the header information from the masterpage and tried it on the website that contains the user control and still nothing

Comment: @Cem I think that I have it somewhat working, however the last row only highlights when the page is refreshed, not when the new line is added.  What do I need to do?

Comment: Are you not refreshing the page when new line added? Can you provide some code please.

Comment: I am not refreshing the page when a new one is added (plus someone can go to the page without adding a new one).  When the detailsview is updated it stores the information in the database and rebinds the gridview.

Comment: I fixed it, I had an error that I had to fix before it would fire.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

So you want the effect to run on the recently updated row?  On the RowUpdated event, you're going to have to render JavaScript statements to run on document ready.  I'm not exactly sure what you can pass up, you probably could pass up the row ID (if it renders, which I think it does), or the current row index.

HTH.